# Java compiler complains "i already defined in main" in my poker program

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn Java on my own and I have no background as a programmer. I'm trying to create a program based on Sedgewick and Wayne's "Programming in Java" that creates an array of a deck of cards and prints out "f" hands of 5 random cards. As I've configured my program so far, I'm getting an error message that says "i" is already defined in main. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Deal
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String[] suit = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };

        String[] rank = 
        {
            "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
        };
        // Creates the deck
        String[] deck = new String[suit.length * rank.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < suit.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < rank.length; j++)
                deck[rank.length*i + j] = rank[i] + " of " + suit[j];

        int f = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) 
        {
           int M = 5;    
           int N = 52;   

            // create permutation 0, 1, ..., N-1
           int[] perm = new int[N];
           for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
               perm[i] = i;

           // create random sample in perm[0], perm[1], ..., perm[M-1]
           for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)  {

           // random integer between i and N-1
           int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (N-i));

           // swap elements at indices i and r
           int t = perm[r];
           perm[r] = perm[i];
           perm[i] = t;
       }

           // print results
           for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
               System.out.println(deck[perm[i]] + " ");
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As my Mom always told me, "believe the error messages". She added, "If they don't seem to make sense, then just read them again." She continued, "If you still can't understand what they're saying, then hey, read them one more time." The problem here is that, uhh, "i" is already defined in main. We don't give error messages enough credit. More often than not, they tell us exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I didn't know what to make of the error message - the comment below cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error means... that you are trying to define the variable `i` which is already defined. There's nothing really more to it.

You have

```
for (int i = 0; ...) {
  ...
  for (int i = 0; ...) { // error here.
  ...
  }
}
```

In the inner loop, you must use a different variable name, `j` for instance.